# How do I convert XML to CSV, when one of the values is a header attribute?

Tags: python, xml, csv, elementtree

I'm trying to convert an XML file into a CSV file using Python. I have two values in the XML that I'm trying to find.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main():

    # define input file
    input_dir = r"my\filepath\input.xml"

    # load the xml file
    tree = ET.parse(input_dir)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # open the output csv file in write mode
    csvfile = open(r'my\filepath\output.csv', 'w', newline='')
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # write the header row
    csvwriter.writerow(['value1', 'value2'])

    # iterate over the CARD elements and write the data rows
    for card in root.iter('CARD'):
        value1= card.find('value1').text
        csvwriter.writerow([value1])

    # Loop through each 'BAR' element and print its 'VALUE2' attribute
    for foo in root.findall('.//BAR'):
        value2= foo.get('VALUE2')
        csvwriter.writerow([value2])

    # close the csv file
    csvfile.close()

main()
```

Right now it almost works. The script writes both values into a csv file, but instead of writing them to align with eachother, they're written one after each other.

So instead of this:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | z1 |
| x2 | z2 |

I get this:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| x1 |  |
| x2 |  |
| z1 |  |
| z2 |  |

**How do I fix this and get the values to go to their respective columns?**

I tried giving the `csvwriter.writerow` function a predefined amount of rows, but it only added commas to my data, while still not shifting the values to the desired columns.

```
# iterate over the CARD elements and write the data rows
for card in root.iter('CARD'):
    value1= card.find('value1').text
    csvwriter.writerow([value1,''])

    # Loop through each 'BAR' element and print its 'VALUE2' attribute
    for foo in root.findall('.//BAR'):
        value2= foo.get('VALUE2')
        csvwriter.writerow(['',value2])
```

I also tried indenting the second `for` loop into the first one, but that didn't help at all. It merely shifted the data around while still staying in the first column.

```
# iterate over the CARD elements and write the data rows
for card in root.iter('CARD'):
    value1= card.find('value1').text
    csvwriter.writerow([value1])

    # Loop through each 'BAR' element and print its 'VALUE2' attribute
    for foo in root.findall('.//BAR'):
        value2= foo.get('VALUE2')
        csvwriter.writerow([value2])
```

Here's the XML I'm trying to convert:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<QUERY_IMPORT CREATEIFNOTFOUND="1" ARCHIVEMODE="-1">
<IDENTITY>export</IDENTITY>
<CARD VALUE2="11">
<value9>2</value9>
<r_id>11</r_id>
<value1>name_of_something</value1>
<r_begin>20040101</r_begin>
<r_end>
</r_end><BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
</CARD>
<CARD VALUE2="12">
<value9>2</value9>
<r_id>12</r_id>
<value1>name_of_other</value1>
<r_begin>20040101</r_begin>
<r_end>
</r_end><BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
<BAR VALUE2="randomvaluestuff">
<VALINTA>1901</VALINTA>
</BAR>
</CARD>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your xml file, please?

Comment: I edited it into the post.

Comment: `randomvaluestuff` is always `1901`. Seems you use the same RNG Sony did :)

Comment: What is this `suoritus` ?

Comment: @СергейКох
It was supposed to be "foo", but it seems i forgot to censor that out. I'm fixing it now into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want nested loops, sure, but just find the BARs from that particular card in the inner loop:

```
    for card in root.iter('CARD'):
        value1 = card.find('value1').text
        for foo in card.findall('.//BAR'):
            value2 = foo.get('VALUE2')
            csvwriter.writerow([value1, value2])
```

Then, given an example XML (truncated from yours, with a bit more variation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<QUERY_IMPORT CREATEIFNOTFOUND="1" ARCHIVEMODE="-1">
    <IDENTITY>export</IDENTITY>
    <CARD VALUE2="11">
        <value1>name_of_something</value1>
        <BAR VALUE2="value2-1" />
        <BAR VALUE2="value2-2" />
        <BAR VALUE2="value2-3" />
    </CARD>
    <CARD VALUE2="12">
        <value1>another_name</value1>
        <BAR VALUE2="value2-4" />
        <BAR VALUE2="value2-5" />
        <BAR VALUE2="value2-6" />
    </CARD>
</QUERY_IMPORT>
```

you'd get

```
name_of_something,value2-1
name_of_something,value2-2
name_of_something,value2-3
another_name,value2-4
another_name,value2-5
another_name,value2-6
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Pandas` to process your file easily with [`pd.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) and export it with [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

pd.read_xml('data.xml', xpath='.//CARD')[['value1', 'VALUE2']]
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)  # to csv
```

Output:

```
>>> df
              value1  VALUE2
0  name_of_something      11
1      name_of_other      12
```

Comment: `VALINTA` wasn't what OP wanted for the second column, though.

Comment: @AKX. Thanks to pointed me out. I fixed my answer.